# how to fix illegal package import checkstyle warning

Tags: java, checkstyle, nimble

I am using "java.lang.reflect.Type" in web app project all working fine..but I am stuck with code review how to fix "java.lang.reflect.Type  illegal package import " -checkstyle warning..
I am more intrested in explanation of this warning.

Thanks

Comment: Are the checkstyle rules the original ones? Or do you have any modifications to them?

Comment: @ DaDaDom I believe checkstyle rules are orignal one, also i can't customize any rule b'cz this code review performed by client so i only have report and my source code in my hand

Comment: @Gan Ask the code reviewer if he messed up his Checkstyle config. This should be by default: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html

Comment: It would probably not be a good idea to ask the reviewer "if he messed up his checkstyle config". ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The original [IllegalImport](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) check only forbids the `sun.*` packages, so you are looking at a custom rule definition made by your client.

The rule simply means that you are not supposed to use classes from certain packages. This can make sense for various reasons. If your rule forbids `java.lang.reflect.Type`, then your client does not want you to use [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Since you say that you may not modify the rules, you will have to find some way to reach your goal without Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Usually packages that are for internal use and version specific. They can be dropped/modified anytime. Like sun.*. Look for anything that is not by default in your Checkstyle config.

[Reference](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html).